# Set number of decimal places input by user and truncate number

Tags: microsoft-excel

I'm trying to create an Excel spreadsheet that the number will sometimes result in the answer having no decimal places and other times numerous decimal places. I want to be able to let the user input how many decimals they want in a cell. If the result has several decimal places I can use the `TRUNC` function to say 2 (or whatever number of) decimals, but if there are no decimal places I want to have 0s to fill to the result. So if the result is 990 I want it to show 990.00. I don't want to have to adjust the zeros from the menu bar.

Example: part of a formula is `=TRUNC(D10-(B7*C$7),D$3)`. `D$3` is the cell that the user can say how many decimals they want. If there are multiple decimal places it works fine but if there are no decimals the `TRUNC` function obviously does nothing for me.

Comment: One caveat to all the great answers is if that cell used a format other then "General" then that format would take precedence. However, this can be further "overridden" by Conditional Formatting the cell to "General"

Comment: Thanks to everyone for the quick answers here! I ended up going with the first formula by MGonet because it was somewhat short and included the TRUNC function I needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modification of formula posted by @Máté Juhász to avoid separator when it is not needed:

```
=TEXT(TRUNC(D10-B7*C$7,D$3),"0" & IF(D$3,".",) & REPT(0,D$3))
```

Without `TRUNC` function a value will be rounded instead of truncation.

```
=TEXT(D10-B7*C$7,"0" & IF(D$3,".",) & REPT(0,D$3))
```

Comment: I ended up using your first formula being it kept the TRUNC function that I needed. Seems to do what I need it to do. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Please try this formula `=TRUNC(D10-(B7*C$7),D$3)&REPT(0,D$3-MAX(0,LEN(TRUNC(D10-(B7*C$7),D$3))-LEN(INT(TRUNC(D10-(B7*C$7),D$3))-1)))`

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`TEXT()`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/office/text-function-20d5ac4d-7b94-49fd-bb38-93d29371225c) function to convert number to the desired format:

`TEXT(D10-(B7*C$7), "0."&REPT("0",D$3))`